# How to set a background for a child component in Angular?

Tags: css, angular

I have a parent component called `landing.component`, which has curretly two child componentes:

```
<app-land-top class="land-top"></app-land-top>
<app-land-btn></app-land-btn>
```

And I would like to set a SVG background to one of them.
I tried doing using the CSS from my parent component, `landing.component.css`, with:

```
.land-top {
  background: #141414 url(assets/entireTop_bg.jpg) no-repeat top left;
  background-size: cover;
```

But it did'nt work.

I did find some questions here at StackOverflow, but I could'nt implement any of them.
They seemed a little confusing.

The ones I took a read were:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388437/8297745 - This one talks about creating a JS Directive, but I am not using JS, I am using TypeScript. (It's a answer for the old AngularJS which I am not using at the moment.). I tried implementing it using TypeScript but could'nt.
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48890991/8297745 - So, this one actually answered the exact same thing I tried that did'nt work.

I believe that the following question is probably what I need, [which is this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60391193/8297745), that the user who answered talked about using `NgClass`, but I did'nt understand.

I tried adding `[ngClass] = "land-top"` to see if it worked, but it did'nt do nothing.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probable reason that it is not working is because in Anguler, parent component css does not apply/affect the child component.

In your case, follow below steps.

1. Define the CSS in the app-land-top.
   component.css file

```css
<app-land-top class="land-top" [ngClass]="{'land-top-bg': condition}"></app-land-top>
```

2. and in your html

```html
<app-land-top class="land-top"></app-land-top>
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi. Yes, it worked. I defined the CSS inside the component itself and the image appeared, thanks.